# WCF Service Behavior Lifetime

Tags: wcf

When in the WCF lifecycle are service behaviors loaded?  How long to they persist?  Would I have to recycle my Service Host to re-apply service behaviors or are they dynamically detected?  Is the lifetime variable based on the type of Service Host(Self,Windows Service, IIS, WAS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are managing the behaviors in the config file, then they load when the WCF service loads.  You would need to restart the service to have any changes to a service behavior reflect in the actual service.  Since WCF is host agnostic, service host behaviors are the same regardless of the medium (WAS, WinSvc, IIS, etc)